# PySpark DataFrame: Mark rows where some column value changes

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DataFrame with columns 'people' and 'timestamp' (plus further columns which are not relevant to the problem). The interpretation is that a user did something at that time.

I would like to group all rows of one 'people' where the 'timestamps' do not differ more than 'threshold' value (e.g. 5 minutes).

Any ideas how I can achieve this in PySpark? Preferrably with a DataFrame as outcome?

Appreciate your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you have columns as `['people','timestamp','activity']`

```
SData = Row("people","session_start", "session_end")

def getSessions(dt):
    info = dt[1]
    data = []
    session_start = info[0][0]
    session_end = info[0][0]
    for x in info[1:]:
        if ((x[1] - session_end) > 5*60*1000):
            data.append(SData(dt[0], session_start, session_end)
            session_start = x[1]
        session_end = x[1]
    data.append(SData(dt[0],session_start, session_end))
    return data


rdd  = df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],(x[1],x[2])))

df = rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x: sorted(x, key=lambda z:z)).flatMap(getSessions).toDF()
```

Basically map it to rdd the back to df.

Another approach without rdd  is to create a udf the return arrays of sessions. Finally we can use explode to get the data row wise.